# how to find the limit of the following sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The sequence $$a_{n}=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+.....\frac{1}{(2n)^2}$$

1. converges to $0$
2. converges to $\frac{1}{2}$
3. converges to $\frac{1}{4}$
4. diverges

Comment: This would would be a better question if you included what you had tried yourself

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. You are encouraged to show any own attempts you have made at the problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{rcccl}
\underbrace{\displaystyle \frac{1}{(2n)^2}+\frac{1}{(2n)^2}+.....\frac{1}{(2n)^2}}_{n+1\text{ terms}}
&\le& \displaystyle \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+.....\frac{1}{(2n)^2}
&\le& \underbrace{\displaystyle \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}+.....\frac{1}{n^2}}_{n+1\text{ terms}} \\
\displaystyle \frac{n+1}{(2n)^2}
&\le& a_n
&\le& \displaystyle \frac{n+1}{n^2} \\
\displaystyle \lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{(2n)^2}
&\le& \displaystyle \lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} a_n
&\le& \displaystyle \lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} \frac{n}{n^2} \\
\displaystyle 0
&\le& \displaystyle \lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} a_n
&\le& \displaystyle 0 \\
\end{array}$$

Hence:
$$\lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} a_n = 0$$

---

## Alternative solution

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} a_{n}
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} \left[\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+.....\frac{1}{(2n)^2}\right] \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} \left[\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \dfrac1{i^2} - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \dfrac1{i^2}\right] \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{2n} \dfrac1{i^2} - \lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \dfrac1{i^2} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac1{i^2} - \lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac1{i^2} \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac{\pi^2}6 - \dfrac{\pi^2}6 \\
&=& 0
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you going: Convergence to $0$ or divergence to $\infty$ seem the easiest to prove, if true. For the former, note that the first term of the sum is the largest, and there are $n+1$ terms in the sum. Write up the resulting inequality, and see if you can prove convergence to $0$. If that fails, try the opposite: The last term is the smallest. Apply the same sort of thinking. If neither seems correct, you may need to work harder. But always try the easy way out first.